# BeautifulSoup parse 'findAll' run error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am trying to parse a site using mechanize and BeautifulSoup and not having any luck, I know can access the site table because I can read and print the entire page...user agent not posted here.

```
html = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("table", id="table-hover")

for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    col = row.findAll('th')
    time = col[0].string
    ais_source = col[1].string
    speed_km = col[2].string
    lat = col[3].string
    lon = col[4].string
    course = col[5].string
    record = ( time, ais_source, speed_km, lat, lon, course )
    print "|".join(record)
```

When I run this code I get the error "NoneType object has no attribute 'findAll'  I'm not able to find a unique table identifier for the page.

Comment: without seeing the html it is hard to suggest a fix

Comment: http://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/index/positions/all/shipid:415660/mmsi:354975000/shipname:ADESSA%20OCEAN%20KING/_:6012a2741fdfd2213679de8a23ab60d3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply a user agent:

```
url = "http://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/index/positions/all/shipid:415660/mmsi:354975000/shipname:ADESSA%20OCEAN%20KING/_:6012a2741fdfd2213679de8a23ab60d3"
import requests
headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
html = requests.get(url,headers=headers).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

table = soup.find("table") # only one table
```

So just unpack the list with something like:

```
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    items = row.text.replace(u"kn","") # remove kn so items line up when unpacking
    time, ais_source, speed_km, lat, lon, course = items.split()[1:7]
    print(time,ais_source,speed_km,lat,lon,course)


(u'21:40', u'T-AIS', u'0', u'6.422732', u'3.406325', u'327')
(u'21:17', u'T-AIS', u'0.1', u'6.42272', u'3.406313', u'311')
(u'20:53', u'T-AIS', u'0', u'6.422688', u'3.406312', u'321')
(u'20:30', u'T-AIS', u'0', u'6.422668', u'3.4063', u'324')
(u'20:07', u'T-AIS', u'0.1', u'6.42266', u'3.406287', u'323')
(u'19:44', u'T-AIS', u'0', u'6.422685', u'3.406273', u'320')
(u'19:20', u'T-AIS', u'0.1', u'6.422687', u'3.406297', u'316')
(u'18:57', u'T-AIS', u'0.1', u'6.422675', u'3.406292', u'308')
(u'18:34', u'T-AIS', u'0.1', u'6.422658', u'3.406327', u'312')
(u'18:10', u'T-AIS', u'0.1', u'6.422723', u'3.406318', u'317')
```

Without it you get a 403 error:

```
<html><body><h1>403 Forbidden</h1>
Request forbidden by administrative rules.
</body></html>
```

Comment: this is the worst use of 403 I have seen in the last year!

Comment: I've got that I'm not supplying it here. Read the first line of the posed question.

Comment: @Dan, your `table = soup.find("table", id="table-hover")` is also incorrect, it would be `soup.find("table",attrs={"class":"table table-hover text-left"})` but there is only one table so it is redundant

Comment: your  `col = row.findAll('th')` is also wrong, my code finds the table and `("table", "table table-hover text-left")` is not what I just added in a comment

Comment: I fixed it..and get a list index out of range here: `time = col[0].string`

Comment: because `col = row.findAll('th')` finds nothing, what are you trying to extract

Comment: `time = row.td.text` is what you need

Comment: I am trying to extract the table data I changed that to `col = row.findAll('td')`

Comment: the rest is probably in `row.text`

Comment: print `row.contents` and you will see

Comment: unfortunately `col = row.findAll('td')` gives me `'noneType object has no attribute 'txt'`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham please post `row.text` as an answer

Comment: @Dan, it is at the bottom of my answer, you will have to match the item with the correct list index not sure which is which